# Box-shadow inside textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is anyone have clue about how to repair it?
My main goal in this code is to change box-shadow if textarea (input type="text" not textarea) value isn't empty. 
And if it is empty the color of box-shadow will be rgba(190, 0, 0, 0.75). What I have seen: If I write into input value="anything" this is working (If-else without AddEventListener). 
I can't do it live, if you know what i mean. Here is the code:

```
    let status1 = document.querySelector("#name");

    status1.addEventListener('change value', function(){
            if (status1.value==""){
                status1.style.boxShadow="inset 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(190, 0, 0, 0.75)";
            }else {
                status1.style.boxShadow="none";
            }
        });
```

So if you would help me i'll appreciate it a lot <3 Take care

Comment: Remove `value` from the event type argument.

Comment: You should use proper phrasing to make the question clear to the other people. The lines you have mentioned are all in a single phrase, making the question less friendly to read.

Comment: @Teemu without it still not working :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Validation function
function validate(element) {

  const ErrorStyle = "inset 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(190, 0, 0, 0.75)";
  const ValidStyle = "none";

  // Field value is invalid if length is 0 (true = has error)
  if (element.value.length === 0) {
    element.style.boxShadow = ErrorStyle;
    return
  }

  // Field value is valid if all tests above are false (no errors).
  element.style.boxShadow = ValidStyle;

}

// Get input field
const nameField = document.querySelector("#name");

// Bind input event to validation function
nameField.addEventListener('input', function (event) { validate(event.target) });

// Initial validation, comment out below to change to "lazy validation"
validate(nameField);
```